# Incrementing a value in a database

Tags: android, database, android-room

I am using android room to store my records. Each record contains main 2 fields: date presented as String and corresponding number of phone unlocks for that day as integer.
I was wondering what is the best way to increment that number in database each time the user unlocks the phone.
Is there a better way than query for current number of unlocks in database, increment it by 1 and update the field?
Is there some clever way to just increment value without making a query first to know exact value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with a simple update query:

```
@Query("UPDATE TableName SET FieldToIncrement = FieldToIncrement + 1 WHERE ID = :id")
public abstract void incrementValue(long id);
```

Comment: Does this work? Because it's not working for me. In my query, the where condition is a IN (:list).. The query is "UPDATE table_name SET field = field + 1 WHERE scomId IN (:ids)"

Comment: Use a method noted with @Transaction that call your method for each value of :list

Answer (score -3):

Just annotate field , that you want increment this annotation

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) private final int id;
```

And when user unlock phone , just create a new instance of your `@Entity`.
For the `id` in constructor of your `@Entity` pass 0 , Room automatically generate the next value.